# mod_rewrite redirect from .png to .php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have:

```
http://www.site.tk/track/aaaa.png
```

I want all .png files that are accessed from that folder to redirect to:

```
http://www.site.tk/track/track.php
```

So when I insert no matter what png file from that folder in another website using:

```
<img src="http://www.site.tk/track/bbbb.png">
```

The user will see the content of the "track.php"

I tryed:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase track

RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]{6}).png /track.php
```

I used "RewriteBase track" because the .htaccess is on the ~/track/ folder.

This is the content of the track.php

```
<?php
$date = date('d-m-Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ref = @$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo gzinflate(base64_decode('6wzwc+flkuJiYGDg9fRwCQLSjCDMwQQkJ5QH3wNSbCVBfsEMYJC3jH0ikOLxdHEMqZiTnJCQAOSxMDB+E7cIBcl7uvq5rHNKaAIA'));

$myFile = "tr.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
fwrite($fh, $myFile = $time ." | ". $date . " | " .$ip. " | " .$ref. " | \r\n\r\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

All .png images will be 1px x 1px as the image that is encoded on base64 inside the tracker.php. I want to use this on emails and forums to see who saw my emails and my profile.

Comment: Do you _really_ have to use `.htaccess` style files for this? If possible you should always place rewriting rules in the main server configuration. These .ht* files are hard to setup and debug, notoriously error prone and really slow the server down.

Comment: I need it to be in .htaccess because I have a webhost not a VPS so I can't access the main server configuration.

Comment: OK, then you have no choice, I am afraid.

Comment: About tracking emails: keep in mind that you will only get clicks when someone displays the html version of your email and then only when he is using a very insecure configuration inside his email client. Typically you will _not_ receive a click when someone looks at your email.

Comment: Why don't you use a system like "piwik" for this?

Comment: Anyways, what is your actual question here? The approach is valid and will work. So what is the issue?

Comment: I get info uf they have enabled to see the images inside an email. Gmail and other email clients have already this feature on so always all the images are displayed. That's why I want when I insert the image to rewrite to track.php. I know is possible but not sure how to set the .htaccess file.

Comment: As said: typically you will _not_ get a click when a user reads an email. You indeed will get a click when a user uses a simple webmailer like gmail or the like (and did not change the configuration). But most people use a real email client and _not_ a webmailer. The reasons why most users (should) have such auto-display disabled simply is security. Using such emails and displaying them is a _huge_ security issue.

Comment: @arkascha The issue is that when I access the http://www.site.tk/track/aaaa.png is not displaying track.php (i know this because I can't find any tr.txt (in this file should be saved the date, time and ip.

Comment: OK, sure, I could guess that you do not see the image. but _why_? I mean : what does your error log file say? Your rewriting log file? What _does_ the client get, if not the image? Answer that and you have the answer to your question. Do not try to _guess_ the issue. read the log files. That is what they are for, that is where the problem is documented.

Comment: @arkascha I don't use piwik because they only track the status of the email and they don't send informations about who saw the email (like the IP of the reader)

Comment: Of course piwik tells you the ip address, referrer, client and stuff like that. Though typically the ip address is without value for you, except for inhouse-use maybe, where static addresses are used.

Comment: I can't access the error log because I am on a webhost that doesn't allow reading of the error log. When I access http://www.site.tk/track/aaaa.png (the png file is an image 1px x 1px) with the .htaccess that I put above in this topic, is like accessing a wrong link. Like a 404 error not found.

Comment: It should rewrite to /track/track.php. And I need to see the IP of who saw my email because I know the location of the receiver and I will search the location based on the IP to see if it matches.

Comment: OK, you can use geo location, indeed. That will work for some requests, though not for all. But exactly then piwik makes sense: it already has such stuff built in. Which does not mean you cannot code that again yourself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a `RewriteBase` but not correctly.
Moreover, your rule internally rewrites to root file `/track.php` (which does not exist) since you put a leading slash (and so, cancels `RewriteBase` action).

You can replace your current code by this one (your htaccess still has to be in `track` folder)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /track/

RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.png$ track.php [L]
```

Comment: Half of the script is working. I mean, now when I access aaaa.png the .htaccess is trying to redirect me to track.php but it can't find it. track.php and aaaa.png are in the same folder (http://www.site.tk/track/)

Comment: Weird behaviour since the code i gave you takes `track` folder into consideration. Try to wait a bit or refresh (maybe clear your browser's cache)

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the path to track.php. Is there needed to tell .htaccess that track.php is inside track?

Comment: That's what `RewriteBase` does. Even without it, this should be working since `png` path does not contain any subdirectory. Requesting `/track/something.png` should go to `/track/track.php`

Comment: My bad. I tryed by using: http://track.site.tk/something.png. Is working now using http://site.tk/something.png. Thanks!